# Infinite Loop in Camel at time of resending to a Kafka Topic

Tags: java, apache-camel

We send a Message to a Kafka topic that goes throught a Camel Route to send to an ActiveMQ Topic, everything is working as expected in there. But now we have another route that send the Message arraive from ActiveMQ Topic to an Another topic of Kafka, that is where Camel enters in an Infinite Loop. Here is my XML of the routes. Why this type of configuration is causing an Infinite Loop?

```
<!--DEFINE KAFKA'S TOPCIS AS ENDPOINT-->
            <endpoint id="tagBlink" uri="kafka:10.0.0.165:9092">
                <property key="topic" value="tagBlink"/>
                <property key="brokers" value="10.0.0.165:9092"/>
            </endpoint>
        <!--END OF KAFKA'S TOPICS's AS ENDPOINT-->

            <endpoint id="testMike" uri="kafka:10.0.0.165:9092">
                <property key="topic" value="testMike"/>
                <property key="brokers" value="10.0.0.165:9092"/>
            </endpoint>

         <!-- Route from Kafka (otherMessage) to ActiveMQ (wherenet.flow.deliveryNotificationProducer)-->
        <route id="route1">
            <from uri="ref:tagBlink"/>
                <!--<process ref="transformToXML" />-->
            <to uri="activemq:topic:myTopic"/>            
            <log message="Routing message from Kafka"/>
        </route>


        <route id="routeAutoGeneratedAMQ">  
            <from uri="activemq:topic:myTopic" />                   
            <to uri="ref:testMike"/>
            <to uri="stream:out" />
        </route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after some tests I read this parameter in the Camel Configuration

```
bridgeEndpoint  Default:false   Camel 2.16.0: If bridgeEndpoint is true, the producer will ignore the topic header setting of the message.
```

So i give a shot to add to my endPoints

```
        <!--DEFINE KAFKA'S TOPCIS AS ENDPOINT-->
            <endpoint id="tagBlink" uri="kafka:10.0.0.165:9092">
                <property key="topic" value="tagBlink"/>
<property key="topic" value="tagBlink"/>
                <property key="brokers" value="10.0.0.165:9092"/>
                  <property key="bridgeEndpoint " value="true"/>
            </endpoint>
        <!--END OF KAFKA'S TOPICS's AS ENDPOINT-->

            <endpoint id="testMike" uri="kafka:10.0.0.165:9092">
                <property key="topic" value="testMike"/>
                 <property key="brokers" value="10.0.0.165:9092"/>
                  <property key="bridgeEndpoint " value="true"/>

            </endpoint>
```

And the infinite loop stoped.